# AngularJs(1.x) routing problem in ngRoute?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-1.6

This is the link for the hotels

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="hotel in vm.hotels">
     <a ng-href="#/hotel/{{ hotel._id }}">{{ hotel.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the route is this

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'angular-app/hotel-list/hotels.html',
      controller: HotelsController,
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .when('/hotel/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'angular-app/hotel-display/hotel.html',
      controller: HotelController,
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
}
```

there is no error in the console, I have put `<div ng-view></div>` in the correct place
but it is not giving what I wanted. Any corrections please?Thank you!

Comment: Since we have no idea of what you wanted, and no idea of what it is actually giving, we can't possibly help.

Comment: when I click on the links,I want it to go to a new route...but is remains on the same page.

Comment: Have you checked if you have any error in the console? If so, what is it? Have you configured routing correctly? Do you have an ng-view in your template? Post all the relevant information and code.

Comment: there is no error in the console, I have put <div ng-view></div>

Comment: Post a complete minimal example, in a plunkr, reproducing the problem.

Comment: Also, it should probably be `#!/` and not `#/`.

Comment: Thank you! the problem is solved I replaced `#/` with `#!/`

Comment: @georgeawg, please never add "Solved" in a question title: instead, either answer it properly or vote to close the question. Thank you. [reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309266/actively-prevent-not-solved-yet-in-title)

Answer (score 0):

With **AngularJS V1.6**, the default hash-prefix used for `$location` hash-bang URLs has changed from the empty string (`''`) to the bang (`'!'`). If your application does not use HTML5 mode or is being run on browsers that do not support HTML5 mode, and you have not specified your own hash-prefix then client side URLs will now contain a `!` prefix. For example, rather than `mydomain.com/#/a/b/c` the URL will become `mydomain.com/#!/a/b/c`

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="hotel in vm.hotels">
     ̶<̶a̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶h̶r̶e̶f̶=̶"̶#̶/̶h̶o̶t̶e̶l̶/̶{̶{̶ ̶h̶o̶t̶e̶l̶.̶_̶i̶d̶ ̶}̶}̶"̶>̶{̶{̶ ̶h̶o̶t̶e̶l̶.̶n̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶}̶}̶<̶/̶a̶>̶
     <a ng-href="#!/hotel/{{ hotel._id }}">{{ hotel.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#-location-)